# How to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: on a method with multiple arguments

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Let's say I have a method with this signature:

```
 -(void)plotPoly:(Polygon *)poly WithColor:(UIColor *)color AndFill:(BOOL)filled;
```

How do I get that **UIColor** and **BOOL** in there as well as the **Polygon**?

Should I wrap them in a **NSArray** and pull them out inside the called method? That would mean I have to change the method sig, right?

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Should we assume from the UIColor that you're on iPhone?

Comment: I am. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes -- if you were on Snow Leopard, you could use a Block to solve this.

Comment: I use the NSArray strategy. In some animations I'm doing, the callback needs six different int values to know how to finish the animation and proceed. (UIView's setAnimationDidStopSelector: also only allows one object to come along...) Packing them up is 1 line of code into the NSArray, and 6 lines to unpack in the callback. Very easily understandable code, though unlikely to impress anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I answered a fairly similar question a few weeks ago.  Answer below edited for this question.

In general, I avoid `NSInvocation` for this kind of work.  It tends to be a maintenance headache and, in particular, creates difficulty in refactoring in the future.

First, given this method:

```
 -(void)plotPoly:(Polygon *)poly WithColor:(UIColor *)color AndFill:(BOOL)filled;
```

It would generally be declared as:

```
 -(void)plotPoly:(Polygon *)aPoly color:(UIColor *)aColor filled:(BOOL)filledFlag;
```

This follows the naming conventions a bit more closely.

Now, what I would do is actually capture the arguments into a simple class that provides an `-invoke` method.

Something with an interface like this:

PolyPlotter.h:

```
@interface  PolyPlotter : NSObject
{
    Polygon *poly;
    UIColor *color;
    BOOL filled;
}

+ plotterWithPoly: (Polygon *) aPoly color: (UIColor *) aColor filled: (BOOL) filledFlag; 

- (void) plot;
@end
```

PolyPlotter.m:

```
@interface PolyPlotter()
@property Polygon *poly;
@property UIColor *color;
@property BOOL filled;
@end

@implementation PolyPlotter
@synthesize poly, color, filled;

+ plotterWithPoly: (Polygon *) aPoly color: (UIColor *) aColor filled: (BOOL) filledFlag; 
{
    PolyPlotter *polygonPlotter = [PolyPlotter new];
    polygonPlotter.poly = aPoly;
    polygonPlotter.color = aColor;
    polygonPlotter.filled = filledFlag;
    return [polygonPlotter autorelease];
}

- (void) plot;
{
    // ... do your plotting here ...
}
@end
```

Usage is straightforward.   Just create an instance of PolygonPlotter and tell it to perform the selector `plot` after delay or on main thread or whatever.

Given the question, I suspect that you might need a bit more context at the time of drawing?  If so, you could pass that information as an argument to `-plot` by, say, declaring the method as:

```
- (void) plot: (UIView *) aViewToPlotIn;
```

Or something like that.

Like I said, slightly more code, but much more flexible and refactorable than the NSInvocation pattern.   For example, you could quite easily make the PolygonPlotter something that could be archived.

Answer (score 9):

Still not exactly what I would call elegant, but less yuck than having to change the whole API is NSInvocation:

```
Polygon *poly;
UIColor *color;
BOOL filled;
// Assume the above variables exist
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMessageSignature:[target messageSignatureForSelector:message]];
[inv setArgument:&poly atIndex:2];
[inv setArgument:&color atIndex:3];
[inv setArgument:&filled atIndex:4];
[inv performSelector:@selector(invokeWithTarget:) withObject:target afterDelay:1];
```

The other best option is just to create a wrapper method that calls the original method you want with appropriate arguments (perhaps given as a dictionary or array), which matches the signature needed to perform after a delay.

Comment: Why does the argument index start at 3 and not 2 (as the docs seem to indicate)?

Comment: It starts at 2.  Arguments 0 and 1 are reserved for the hidden `self` and `_cmd` parameters.

Comment: Sorry about that. Typoed the first and then just incremented for the next ones.

Comment: do you mean 'invocationWithMethodSignature' ? Still this method does not work for me.

Comment: What happens to the lifetime of this NSInvocation object? If you perform the selector after a delay, at the end of the current runloop this NSInvocation object should autorelease, and hence won't be around for the delay. And if calling this from an object that itself won't be around long (i.e. a modal view controller calling a delegate on the next run loop) then you can't store the NSInvocation in the calling object.

Comment: @Michael Waterfall: You need to retain the arguments, or they won't be available when the NSInvocation is invoked. I retained the arguments I used, and then released them after a delay greater than the invocations, so as not to cause a leak.

Answer (score 4):

Joe Hewitt's Three20 library has some advanced versions of performSelector that you might find useful (I only post a snippet):

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)p1 withObject:(id)p2 withObject:(id)p3 {
  NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
  if (sig) {
    NSInvocation* invo = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
    [invo setTarget:self];
    [invo setSelector:selector];
    [invo setArgument:&p1 atIndex:2];
    [invo setArgument:&p2 atIndex:3];
    [invo setArgument:&p3 atIndex:4];
    [invo invoke];
    if (sig.methodReturnLength) {
      id anObject;
      [invo getReturnValue:&anObject];
      return anObject;
    } else {
      return nil;
    }
  } else {
    return nil;
  }
}
```

Just add them to a Category of `NSObject`.

Comment: How would I implement the afterDelay: function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe NSArray is a reasonable solution, and yes that would mean changing the method signature to taking an NSArray* as its sole argument.